# Does Teddy become a werewolf?

Tags: harry-potter, werewolf

Teddy Lupin is the son of Remus Lupin, a werewolf.  Does this condition get passed down from father to son?  It seems that Remus is afraid that this is the case, but I don't recall whether or not there is any evidence that this actually occurs.

Does Teddy Lupin end up being a werewolf?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. When Lupin came to announce Teddy's birth to Bill's cottage in DH, he didn't say anything about it; but in general appeared extremely happy. If the baby had been a werewolf, he would surely have been less excited.

Also, from [Bloomsbury Live Chat](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html) with J.K. Rowling on 2007/07/30,

> **Vio91:** Is teddy lupin a werewolf
>   **J.K. Rowling:** No, he's a Metamorphmagus like his mother.

Comment: You're ignoring the obvious. Teddy was newborn, and no full moon had passed yet. Lupin could not know whether Teddy was a werewolf yet, since a hereditary werewolf would logically have no scars. At the battle of Hogwarts, there would not have been time to mention this to Harry. Of course, they might have figured it out before Teddy was born, but that's assuming that a werewolf could transform in the womb (not shielded from moonlight or considered part of the mother) and assuming wizards have ultrasound.

Answer (score 6):

## No - lycanthropy can only be passed on by a werewolf bite.

In “Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them”, it’s stated that humans will only become werewolves when bitten.

> “Humans turn into werewolves only when bitten. There is no known cure, though recent developments in potion-making have to a great extent alleviated the worst symptoms.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

This seems fairly conclusive - the condition of lycanthropy can only be passed on through a werewolf bite, so Teddy Lupin would therefore not “inherit” being a werewolf.

**In addition, a Pottermore writing by JKR says it’s never seen to be hereditary.**

In a writing on Pottermore, JKR specifically addresses whether lycanthropy can be inherited from a werewolf parent, and says there’s never been any sign of this happening.

> Werewolves generally reproduce by attacking non-werewolves. The stigma surrounding werewolves has been so extreme for centuries that very few have married and had children. However, where werewolves have married human partners, there has been no sign of their lycanthropy being passed to their offspring. 
> <sub><sup>*[Werewolves (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/werewolves)*</sup></sub>

Since Teddy Lupin is the only child of a werewolf that we know of in the series, this seems like an intentional way of implying that he wasn’t a werewolf.

Answer (score 1):

From *Order of the Phoenix*

> Fenrir Greyback is, perhaps, the most savage werewolf alive today. He regards it as his mission in life to bite and to conta­minate as many people as possible; he wants to create enough were­wolves to overcome the wizards. Voldemort has promised him prey in return for his services. Greyback specialises in children... Bite them young, he says, and raise them away from their parents, raise them to hate normal wizards.

If it were hereditary, the werewolves could much more easily multiply their numbers by having large families, and attract less attention, too.

Answer (score 0):

No, the werewolf condition is not hereditary. It can ONLY be passed on through a bite. Teddy might have been half werewolf, but he is only a Metamorphmagus.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  If you have any evidence to support this which the accepted answer doesn't, by all means include it; otherwise there's not really much point in posting an answer.  Try having a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour): you get a free badge!

Comment: It doesn't necessarily disbunk this theory, but Lupin himself feared his son would be a werewolf so it suggests it's at least plausible (if not possible) for it to be hereditary.

Comment: Since a Metamorphmagus can change his/her appearance at will, it might have counterbalanced his werewolfishness, assuming he was one.